# Heroku Rails 3.2 ActionView::Template::Error ( ...(file)... has a invalid UTF-8 byte sequence):

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, asset-pipeline

Hey I'm getting this error in my Rails app (Heroku, production, Rails 3.2.3):

```
ActionView::Template::Error (/app/vendor/assets/javascripts/star-rating/jquery.MetaData.js has a invalid UTF-8 byte sequence):
3: <head>
4:   <title>ContactTool</title>
5:   <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
6:   <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
7:   <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
8: </head>
9: <body>
app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:6:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__630446545548622900_53107960'
```

It started to happen after changing to lazy loading in production, which I need:

application.rb

...

```
if defined?(Bundler)
  # If you precompile assets before deploying to production, use this line
  # Bundler.require(*Rails.groups(:assets => %w(development test)))
  # If you want your assets lazily compiled in production, use this line
  Bundler.require(:default, :assets, Rails.env)
end
```

...

How do I fix this? Thanks!

Update:

I removed the file just to test whether or not the error was only related to that file, and it was. Without this file everything works fine. I will need this file though, so if anybody knows why I'd get an error on the utf8

Comment: Have you tried replacing `jquery.MetaData.js` with a new copy? To me, that error sounds like you've got some garbage character in that file.

Comment: i'll try that. yeah i thought i might as well but i don't remember even opening it.

Comment: nope, that definitely was not the issue, after updating the file i get the same error. could still be some garbage characters but it's nothing i've inadvertently added. gotta be something else.

Comment: Continuing the binary search...Does removing L6 remove the error? If so, then it's from some way the JS assets are being compiled. Maybe try removing required JS and adding them in, for a really dull way of doing this (I still haven't moved to the asset pipeline). If you change your localhost version to production, do you get the same error?

Comment: having a unrelated postgres error in production so i'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Put `# encoding: utf-8` on the first line in your view (note the #)

There was a change in rails 3 (if i'm not mistaken) that does something with utf-8 encoding